# Convert Number to blanks in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I have converted my numeric data to a `dd-mm-yyyy` formatted output. Many of the records in the table I am pulling data from contain dates like this 0 0 99 (m,d,yy) or 99 99 99 (mm,dd,yy). The business has requested that these data elements come back as blanks in the results tables. No field is to be nullable in the data results.

Here is the code that I have at this point:

```
,CASE 
    WHEN LEN(PSEFMO) = 1 AND PSEFMO  > 0  
      THEN '0' 
    ELSE 
      REPLACE(CAST(PSEFMO AS VARCHAR(2)),'0',' ')  
 END + CAST(PSEFMO as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
        CASE 
          WHEN LEN(PSEFDA) < 2 AND PSEFDA <> 0 
            THEN '0' 
            ELSE ' ' 
        END  + CAST(PSEFDA as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
                 CASE 
                    WHEN (PSEFCT = 0) THEN '19' ELSE '20' END + 
                 CASE 
                    WHEN PSEFYR < 10 AND LEN(PSEFYR) = 1 AND PSEFYR <> 0 
                      THEN '0' 
                      ELSE ' ' 
                 END  + CAST(PSEFYR as varchar(2))  
                  AS [FROMDATE]
```

There results look like this:

```
  0- 0-19 0
  11- 22-19 97
  11- 22-19 97
   0- 0-19 0
  08-07-2009
  05- 12-2005
  08-09-2002
  08-07-2009
  0- 0-19 0
```

What can I do to convert the 0-0-19-0 to blanks and ensure that all months start in the first position? Also note that the field PSEFCT incoming data is either 0 or 1 if it is 0 then the century is 19 if 1 then 20. I got this work however I will need to blank out this field also....

Any help will be appreciated as this is a production conversion issue.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the logic for deciding whether a specific row should be replaced with a blank?  I'm not sure I understand your desired output.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a few good and bad incoming rows, including all the columns you use in the `CASE` statement?

Comment: The powers that be want it a bit different now:                      I am to make the incoming data that looks like this 00/00/00 = 1901-01-01 and the incoming data that looks like this 99/99/99 = 2199/12/31. No returned results should have a blank...

Comment: Are all the values coming in as ints?

Comment: @orgtigger, the values are decimal (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover all the cases that you listed, this will NOT deal with incorrect days in a month (30 days in february for example)
Still seems a bit hackish though, any way to convert the data into a date before sending it?

edit: swapped greater than signs for less than signs
Edit: Silly programmer, I swapped out the less than values so that they were one higher than the values I wanted (> 12 does not include 12 but > 13 does) 
edit: added the missing 'end' statement

```
,case 
   when PSEFYR = 99 then '21'
   when PSEFCT = 0 then '19'
   else '20'
 end
+ case 
   when PSEFYR < 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(1))
   else Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(2))
   end
+ '-'
+ case 
   when PSEFMO  = 0 then '01'
   when PSEFMO  < 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFMO as varchar(1))
   when PSEFMO  < 13 then Cast(PSEFMO as varchar(2))
   else '12'
 end
+ '-'
+ case 
   when PSEFDA = 0 then '01'
   when PSEFDA > 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(1))
   when PSEFDA > 32 then Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(2))
   else '31'
 end AS [FROMDATE]
```

Comment: @ortigger, I tweekend the > 10 & >12:
    ,case 
    end
    + case 
    when PSEFYR < 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(1)) 
    when pSEFYR = 0 THEN '01'
    else Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(2))
    + '-'
    + case 
    when PSEFMO  = 0 then '01'
    when PSEFMO < 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFMO as varchar(1)) 
    when PSEFMO < 12 then cast(PSEFMO as varchar(2)) 
    else '12'
    end
    + '-'
    + case 
    when PSEFDA = 0 then '01'
    when PSEFDA < 10 then '0' + Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(1))
    when PSEFDA < 31 then Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(2))
    else '31' end
    end AS [FROMDATE]

Comment: For some reason I was not able to get the code above to format correctly, I apologize for the crummy appearance. I am still having problems with returned results here is a sample:                        psefmo       psefda       psefyr FROMDATE
11  22  97     1997-12-22
11  22  97     1997-12-22
0  0  0     1900
8  7  9     2009
5  12  5     2005
8  9  2     2002
8  7  9     2009
0  0  0     1900

Comment: @INDYGAL I fixed the greater than, less than issue. Also had a month/day issue. The format was based on your comment YYYY-MM-DD and not your post MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: @ortigger,  I modified code again> ,case when PSEFCT = 0 then '19'else '20' end + case when PSEFYR < 10 and PSEFYR <> 0 then '0' + Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(1)) when pSEFYR = 0 THEN '01'else Cast(PSEFYR as varchar(2)) + '-' + case when PSEFMO < 10 and PSEFMO <> 0 then '0' + Cast(PSEFMO as varchar(1)) when PSEFMO > 9 then cast(PSEFMO as varchar(2)) when PSEFMO  = 0 then '01' end + '-' + case when PSEFDA < 10 and PSEFDA <> 0 then '0' + Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(1)) when PSEFDA > 9 then Cast(PSEFDA as varchar(2))
when PSEFDA = 0 then '01'end end AS [FROMDATE] -- results in next comment

Comment: here are the funky results....                                                                     psefmo psefda psefyr FROMDATE
11 22 97 1997-11-22
0 0 0 1901
8 7 9 2009
5 12 5 2005
8 9 2 2002
8 7 9 2009
0 0 0 1901
0 0 0 1901
7 1 98 1998-07-01
0 0 0 1901

Comment: I am having a dilly of a time with the comment editor.

Comment: I missed an 'end' for the year case, I fixed the post please try it again.

Comment: I finally figured it out, the placement of the END for each statement must be correlated with the statement itself.  Now I am getting the correct results:                                                   psefda psefyr FROMDATE
0 0 1901-01-01
22 97 1997-11-22
22 97 1997-11-22
22 97 1997-11-22
7 9 2009-08-07
12 5 2005-05-12                                    Thank you @orgtigger for the code to resolve the issue and  for the time and effort on your part! Have a wonderful day.

Comment: @INDYGAL does that mean a shiny green check for me? :)

Comment: Yes @orgtigger!  Thanks so very much for your help, it is most appreciated.